# saber se o numero é par ou impar em um array simples

Tags: c, array

```
  float vet[10];
//processamento
for(x=0;x<=9;x++)
{
    printf("\n informe o %d° número:",x+1);
    scanf("%f",&vet[x]);
//saída de dados
    if (vet[x] % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("\n O número %2.f é par",vet[x]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n O número %2.f é impar",vet[x]);
```

como posso saber se o valor que eu digitar vai ser impar ou par

Comment: quando executo o mesmo aparece isso aqui:  error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')

Comment: O conceito de par/ímpar é aplicável a inteiros, assim como o operador `%` (resto da divisão) que é definido para inteiros. Para valores reais existe a função `fmod` de <math.h>.

Answer (score 0):

O código está retornando esse erro porque o operador `%` só funciona com números `inteiros`, sendo que o seu vetor possui tipo `float`.

Basta utilizar `typecasting`, que consiste em colocar o novo tipo do dado entre parênteses antes da variável. Porém, ao fazer isso, você não muda o tipo da variável, você apenas converte o dado.

Caso queira guardar o valor convertido, é preciso declarar outra variável. No seu caso, isso não é preciso, porque você apenas verifica se a condição é verdadeira ou não, e depois descarta o valor obtido.

Coloque o `(int)` antes da variável para convertê-la:

```
  if ((int)vet[x] % 2 == 0)
  {
     printf("\n O número %1.f é par",vet[x]);
  }
  else
  {
     printf("\n O número %1.f é impar",vet[x]);
  }
```

Perceba que os `%2.f` precisam ser substituídos por `%1.f`, para não mostrar as casas decimais, mas não podem ser substituídos por `%d`, porque o valor de `vet[x]` ainda é um float.

Notei que nesse trecho do código você não declarou a variável `x` que usou no `for`, não esquece de fazer isso depois.

Fonte: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm